# Android delete fragment on ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have used ViewPager2 with Fragments as an example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2). When i delete first position, fragment is still showing. Do you have any suggestion for this situation.

```
class PagerAdapter(
    private var activity: FragmentActivity,
    private var itemCount: Int,
    private val conversationId: Long,
    private val currentMediaOffset: Int,
    private val callBack: PhotoViewerActivity.OnPageListener
): FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
val list = mutableListOf<SwipePhotoViewerFragment>()
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    if (position < list.size) {
        list[position].setCallback(callBack)
        return list[position]
    }

    val fragment = SwipePhotoViewerFragment.create(
            conversationId,
            position,
            currentMediaOffset
    )
    fragment.setCallback(callBack)
    list.add(fragment)

    return fragment
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemCount
}

fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    val fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(list[position]).commit()
    list.removeAt(position)
    itemCount--
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when we call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, android will call method `getItemId()` in adapter, to check if the item has been updated or not then it returns the position in source code. which basically means in list if you have something like 0-1-2-3-4-5 , if you remove i=2 position , it becomes to 0-1-2-3-4 but the weird thing is `i` won't change and the data won't update in adapter.

So what you have to do is override `getItemId()`:

```
val listOfData :MutableList<*> = ArrayList()

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long 
{
    return lisfOfData[position].hashCode().toLong()
}
```

this will ensure that each fragment is unique and updated in adapter.